# No data from Firestore even after creating an index after following link

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using Firebase and React to build an FAQ section that I get from Firestore. These items need to be ordered by a field attribute called "order". Everything works in the emulator but when i go live, firebase asks me to follow a link to create an index, i create the index but afterwards nothing appears on the website and `console.log` says there is an empty array even though there is data.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const colRef = collection(db, "FAQs");
      const q = query(
        colRef,
        where("category", "==", "CustomerFAQs"),
        where("adminPublish", "==", "true"),
        orderBy("order")
      );
      const snapshots = await getDocs(q);
      const docs = snapshots.docs.map((doc) => {
        return doc;
      });

      setCustomerFAQs(docs);
      console.log("CustomerFAQs: ", docs);
    })();
  }, []);
```

[image: Data entry in firestore]
[image: Index that was created]

Please let me know where i'm missing something.

Comment: FYI you should probably store the boolean value `true` instead of the string value "true" for `adminPublish`.

Comment: @DougStevenson, why boolean as opposed to string? I've opted for string because when a user enters boolean values from the app into Firestore, the value somehow ends up being a string.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time explaining to someone why "true" works, but not "TRUE" or "True", which are both valid in some languages.  A boolean is always a boolean and cannot be mistaken. It also requires less storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query results are likely correct.  Your filter just doesn't match any documents.

Your query filters on a category value "CustomerFAQs", but the document you're showing contains a differnet value "customerFAQs" with a lowercase "c". Change either the query or data appropriately and you will get a document match.

If the query couldn't use an index, the query would result in an error, not an empty set of documents.